# how would you set up the GUI for a web-based board game structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a web-based board game like reversi.  I created a similar game in python before but now I want to try to implement it using javascript/jquery/html/css.

The main thing I'm wondering about is how to set up the GUI for the board game in the browser?  I have two ideas.  One, create an html table structure containing 64 cells.  Second, create 64 floating divs.

I realize that for the layout of a website, tables are unreliable and inconsistent across browsers but in the case of a game like this, would a tabular setup be easier to work with?

Comment: "tables are unreliable and inconsistent across browsers" False. Tables are the most consistent. That said, I don't think your data is 'tabular' data, so semantically I can't recommend using a `<table>`

Comment: @Ktash I would agree with you, except the OP said *for the layout of a website*.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Haha, I'm not sure which part you disagree with lol. But I'd be more than happy to defend my points. Though if we do that, we should probably move to [chat] ;)

Comment: dammit! why isn't there a proper solution to this? I wanted to say inline-blocks which would be a modern equivalent for such a job but there is the white-space problem; and when you float you have the clear problem; and tables are almost impossible to style decently. I wish someone does something about it soon and makes all the browsers accept it.

Comment: @Ege: what’s wrong with tables as a solution? In what way can you not decently style table representing a reversi game?

Comment: Somehow this has turned into a table vs div argument. For a game you wouldn't use either in a conventional way unless you wanted to either complicate animation options or not animate at all. Granted you COULD use either traditionally, but from a game perspective you would be limiting yourself by choosing to lay out your board as a literal table or floating div's. In any case, your game state should be handled by a constant js object and not so much DOM. So you should think of your "grid" from a data perspective and not from an html perspective.

Comment: well, for starters, as far as my experience goes you can never use css3 properties like box-shadows or rounded corners unless you put a div inside tds, which would make the markup horrendous to look at. And layout wise, margins and paddings always feel easier than cellpadding and cellspacing.

Comment: @KaiQing: totally agree that your game’s *state* wouldn’t be held in the DOM. I think I see where you’re coming from — you’re saying use absolute positioning instead of floats or tables, so that each grid square can move independently of the others.

Comment: @Ege: the following example seems to work fine in Chrome 2 and Firefox 3.5, the earliest versions of those browsers that support both `box-shadow` and `border-radius`: http://jsfiddle.net/9deKf/. I do take your point though, there would be some styling limitations with tables. I’d just expect them not to matter for a reversi board.

Comment: yeah, from a designer point of view I'd like to be able to do some heavy styling work but you're definitely right semantically. I assumed since he even considered using floats the html would have to be for purely graphical purposes.

Comment: @Paul - Yes, independent movement. This way he could animate moving between grids effortlessly instead of worrying about where any element happens to reside from a literal DOM standpoint. I don't really know what kind of animation reversi involves, but a creative mind can animate anything and for sure a slightly animated game is infinitely more impressive than one that just changes backgrounds or pops images into a box. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like reversi, I think a table is appropriate — beyond the visuals, it’s a decent semantic representation of the content, i.e. the state of the game board. (`<div>`s wouldn’t perform the same job, as they don’t represent the relationship between rows and columns.)

I’d expect a table to be as easy to work with as `<div>`s: possibly slightly easier, as you don’t have to write any CSS to get the two-dimensional layout, although you might have to use slightly more code to generate the HTML, depending on how you’ve got the game modelled in code. (E.g. If you’ve already modelled the game as cells within rows, it’s easy. If not, you’ll have to keep track of that in code when generating the HTML.)

Comment: Agreed.  The board is an 8 by 8 table.  The dimensions will not change.  Semantically, table tags make perfect sense to me in this situation.

Comment: I'm all against tables _for layout_ but this board _is_ a table. Using divs would make _less_ sense here.

Comment: Semantic markup refers to markup best supporting the meaning of the content. Considering the content here is some background color and game pieces (all generated in the process of playing the game) the markup does very little to point to the meaning of the content - in other words the content is semantically vague to start with. If you care about correct semantic representation you need to use a role attribute (eg. role=game_board) - in which case both divs and table will be appropriate for this layout. (or if you really care you can use dublin core for proper semantic description of content).

Comment: @Michal: sure — as far as semantics goes we’re in vague human interpretation territory here, rather than anything specific to this game. I’m not very familiar with Reversi, but I’d argue that chess, for example, isn’t semantically vague: its board has cells labelled with identifiers (A-H, 1-8), and games can be carried out via post using this system.

Comment: Semantics refers to providing clues to interpretation (to reduce vagueness). The labels on a chess board do not reduce vagueness or specify role - they are helpers to understanding the workings of a chessboard and they are a vocabulary to work with a chessboard. In terms of machine readability, which is the crux of semantic web, simply using a table or a div is not sufficient to reduce vagueness . In other words I am simply arguing for using the word "semantic" properly and fully realizing what it implies.

Comment: @Michal: yup, I’m not talking about machine-readable semantics. (I’m not aware that there are any agreed machine-readable semantics for reversi yet.)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for divs over tables. Mainly because browser performance suffers (on some browsers like older versions of IE) when you manipulate table elements. Additionally using divs will give you much more layout and styling possibilities.  It is a bit easier to generate a "div"-based board as you don't have to worry about inserting tr's.

Other than that it does not really matter which way you going to go

Answer (score 0):

I would use divs because they seem neater to me but you'll probably find that jQuery is SO flexible it wouldn't matter too much if you did use tables.

Imagine your grid structure like this:

```
<div id="#grid">
    <div class="row1 column1"></div>
    <div class="row1 column2"></div>
    <div class="row1 column3"></div>
    ... (and so on) ...
</div>
```

Cells could then be selected uniquely using jQuery like:

```
$(".row1 .column2").css("background-color","#ccc")
```

CSS might look like:

```
    #grid div{
       display:inline;
       float:left;
       height:100px;
       width:100px;
       ... and so on ...
    }
```

Comment: Really? You’re trying to represent rows and columns in HTML, and you’d pick `<div>`s over the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags? (Note that `tr` stands for “table row”.)

Comment: wouldn't display:inline prevent width&height from being rendered?

Comment: @Ege: `float:left` trumps `display:inline`. The latter is there to fix float bugs in IE 6 and I think 7.

Comment: I am sorry but giving your layout class names for board only complicates things. In reality you will be working with an array representing the board so you can access any HTML element by it's index (which is an equivalent on your "virtual board"). For click handling you will be passed an element reference so again you are introducing an unnecessary complexity by adding rows and column classes.

Comment: @michael - exactly what I was saying in my comment and post. This is not a matter of DOM but game logic. And being that, I doubt a complicated literal DOM grid is the answer no matter which way you choose to go.

Comment: @Ege: sure, I think http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html is the canonical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple decision, if layout is tabular then use a table. There's no absolute insistence on not using tables. Just because they have just been overused in the past does not mean there aren't good, justifiable uses today.

Floats can mimic a table but will not handle overflow conditions well. A table will automatically reflow to accommodate the contents of its cells. If overflow isn't an issue, then by all means consider floats.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a mathematical approach based off the available dimensions of the user screen and such. I would create a js object based off basic division and assign the pieces as position absolute elements with the proper offsets. It would be especially easy for a game like reversi and since you're using the jQuery library already it shouldn't be a problem to deal with the initial calculation and rewriting of game piece positions.

So I would have one div ('#container') that's width:100%; height:100%; or whatever is a logical game board.
Then divide the $('#container').width() and $('#container').height() by the applicable tiles and map out a js object to create a data grid and the expected width and height of each cell.
Then attach a click listener on the container element that records x and y and cross references it with the results of your board division results from the initial load.
Then define starting coordinates for your initial pieces, if any, and draw them.

That's vague, I know, but the general idea is to eliminate the literal concept of a grid at all and think of the whole thing as an empty piece of paper with floating boxes inside it.

Sorry for the longwinded response. I guess the end result for me is a suggestion to use divs. Since your board is a fixed proportion, there's no reason to think of it as tabular anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my mind from my earlier comment.

Use `<div>` with meaningful class names, and use the CSS `display` property as appropriate, using the values of `table`, `table-row`, and `table-cell`

The whole board would be `display: table`, each row `display: table-row`, and each space `display: table-cell`

See my example fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/XyK7s/